# Javascript click eventlistener on div works only once

Tags: javascript, focus, contenteditable, addeventlistener

I'd like everytime the user click over the #box div to focus within the #innerbox contenteditable.

I'm using the following code, but it only works once:

```js
document.getElementById('box').addEventListener('click', function(){
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('innerbox').focus();
  }, 0);
});
```

```css
#innerbox{
  border: 1px solid;
}

#box{
  border: 1px blue solid;
  padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div id="innerbox" contenteditable="true" style="min-height:26px;" onkeyup="myFunction()"></div>
</div>
```

there are no other 'click' listeners on the #box

**EDIT:**
A difference i have with the snippet above is that the #innerbox div gets removed and recreated in the DOM, and it's after it gets recreated the first time that click eventlistener doesn't work anymore, can this be the issue?

**EDIT 2:**
I tried using

```
$('#box').on('click', '#innerbox', function(){
  $('#innerbox').focus();
});
```

for dynamically created elements but also doesn't work.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. (works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/p3Lfczsx/)

Comment: seems like you would want to prevent the default action and also check to make sure the click is not inside of the child.

Comment: The code looks fine except there are few errors which actually should not hamper from executing the function you are trying to. Could you provide more detail on your issue?

Comment: So what do you mean it only runs once. Is there other code on the page that replaces the content?

Comment: @Pete label is not going to focus a contenteditable.

Comment: code would be too long, are more js pages, but a difference that may be the culprit i'm thinking of, can be the fact that the #innerbox div gets removed and recreated in the DOM, and it's then that click eventlistener doesn't work anymore

Comment: @ChrisG i edited with update

Comment: @notsure removing and recreating the div is the issue, yes. The event handler will not survive that. As you found out, jQuery's `.on()` can be used to solve this.